# Setting a placeholder image/HTML while electron can't connect to URL

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm trying to display an image in my electron app that would indicate that the app couldn't load the URL. Also, the app should keep trying to connect again to the server every 3 seconds. Basically, the behavior I'm looking for is like in chrome when you get this screen:
[image]

So far, I've managed to get the part where the app persistently keeps trying to connect, but I can't figure out how to display custom HTML in case the connection fails. This is what I have so far:

```
const electron = require('electron');


function connect(win, host, port) {
    win.loadURL(`http://${host}:${port}`);
}


function main() {
    const win = new electron.BrowserWindow({
        icon: __dirname + '/favicon.ico',
        show: false
    });
    const host = process.argv.includes('--host') ? process.argv[process.argv.findIndex(arg => arg == '--host') + 1] : 'localhost';
    const port = process.argv.includes('--port') ? process.argv[process.argv.findIndex(arg => arg == '--port') + 1] : '12345';
    global.argv = process.argv;
    global.env = process.env;
    connect(win, host, port);

    win.webContents.on('did-fail-load', () => {
        setTimeout(() => connect(win, host, port), 3000);
    });

    win.once('ready-to-show', () => {
        win.show();
        win.focus();
    });
}


electron.app.on('ready', main);
```

I've tried passing custom HTML via html data URL (using the `loadURL`) function, but every time I use `loadURL` again when reconnecting to the server, the "custom" HTML gets overwritten by a white screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically there. All that's left is loading your error page.

Say you have an `error.html`:

```
<body>
  <h1>Error connecting</h1>
</body>
```

Your main code could look like this:

```
let mainWindow
function createWindow () {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})

  mainWindow.webContents.on("did-fail-load", () => {
      mainWindow.loadFile("error.html");
      setTimeout(connect, 3000);
  });

  connect();
}

function connect() {
    console.log("trying to connect");
    mainWindow.loadURL("https://madeupsitexxxxxxxxxxx.com");
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);
```